# X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM not working if don't use www

Tags: x-frame-options

Angular 7, IIS 7, C# .NET Core, FireFox

For my site: https://www.example.com, x-frames fail if the user uses https://example.com  (note the absence of www)

The header I am building is:
Headers.Add("X-frame-options", "ALLOW FROM https://www.example.com,https://example.com");

I've tried numerous iterations of this, and no matter what I try, I can't get it to work for both:
https://www.example.com
https://example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034#section-2.1):

> Wildcards or lists to declare multiple domains in one ALLOW-FROM
> statement are not permitted

and [Usage Design Pattern and Example Scenario for the ALLOW-FROM
Parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034#section-2.3.2.3)

> 1. A page that wants to render the requested content in a frame
>    supplies its own origin information to the server providing the
>    content to be framed via a query string parameter.

e.g. using a query string on the URL.

> 2. The server verifies that the hostname meets its criteria, so that
>    the page is allowed to be framed by the target resource.  This
>    may, for example, happen via a lookup of a whitelist of trusted
>    domain names that are allowed to frame the page.  For example,
>    for a Facebook "Like" button, the server can check to see that
>    the supplied hostname matches the hostname(s) expected for that
>    "Like" button.
> 3. The server returns the hostname in "X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM"
>    if the proper criteria was met in step #2.
> 4. The browser enforces the "X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM" header.

---

Note that `X-Frame-Options` is superseded by [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)
 where the [frame ancestors directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) **does** allow you to provide a list.

---

That said, it doesn't really make sense to host the same website on `www.example.com` and `example.com`. Pick one of them to be canonical and issue a `301` redirect from the other to it.

Then you only need to allow the canonical one in `X-Frame-Options`.

Comment: I don't want to use wildcards, because my test site is 'test.example.com', and that could potentially allow contamination by my test system.  That's why I avoided the wildcard.  I actually am using CSP, but FireFox doesn't appear to think that is enough?  FireFox complains if I don't use X-Frame-Options

When I originally built the site, it was www.example.com, and people got lazy, typed in 'example.com'.  So my solution was to simply add a host header for 'example.com'.

I

Comment: After putting in a URL rewriter to redirect all users from https://Example.Com to https://www.example.com, then putting only https://www.example.com in my 'ALLOW-FROM' header, that did correct the problem.